# How to make Mongoose query case insensitive?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

```
      const userExists = await Users.exists({ username: username });
```

How can I make this userExists boolean case insensitive?

**

It is resulting false if I enter anurag,Anurag,aNurag

**

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use Regex

```
const userExists = await Users.exists({ username: { '$regex': username, $options: 'i' } })
```

`i` in options stands for `case-insensitive`.